# Imports in Blueprints Cloudify 3.4.1

Tags: plugins, import, cloudify

I have uploaded the plugins in the Cloudify Manager.
Do i need to still mention the plugins in the import section of the blueprint.yaml file??/
If Yes, what will be the syntax to write the imports for the uploaded plugins?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The imports section is a reference to the types and plugins that should be used in the blueprint.
This means that even if the manager has all the plugins uploaded, you should still mention what plugins will be used in this blueprint.

This is how the imports section looks on the manager blueprint:

```
tosca_definitions_version: cloudify_dsl_1_3

imports:
  - http://www.getcloudify.org/spec/cloudify/3.4/types.yaml
  - http://www.getcloudify.org/spec/fabric-plugin/1.4/plugin.yaml
  - http://www.getcloudify.org/spec/openstack-plugin/1.4/plugin.yaml
  - types/manager-types.yaml
```

You can find further explanation on the blueprint structure here:
http://docs.getcloudify.org/3.4.1/intro/blueprints/